# getting data from specific table/website using XPATH

Tags: python, xml, xpath

im trying to use xpath to get some values from a website.
http://irvingmasjid.org/index.php

If you look to the top right corner should be a table there with some values. What i want to get is the 6 numbered values below the title "Adhan" meaning:

4.39, 6.20 etc..

I know that you need to find something unique in the html code and i found this:

```
//*[@id='slideshow-305-57546dc930cff']
```

but i have no idea on how to move on from there to get to the values that i want. I am trying something like this:

```
dict = {}

url = "http://irvingmasjid.org/index.php"

rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='slideshow-305-57546dc930cff']/")


for id,row in enumerate(blabla:::)
    get the values here...
```

Never used much python also xpath so sorry for not being able to provide more information. Please if you have code example it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is interesting about this case is that you *don't even need to parse HTML* - the data you are up to is being retrieved from a different URL:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> url = "http://irvingmasjid.org/salah2016.php"
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> 
>>> pprint(response.json())
{u'_day_of_year': u'157',
 u'adhan_asr': u'5:09',
 u'adhan_dhuhr': u'1:29',
 u'adhan_fajr': u'4:39',
 u'adhan_isha': u'9:49',
 u'adhan_maghrib': u'8:37',
 u'day': u'12:37',
 u'j_asr': u'6:00',
 u'j_dhuhr': u'1:45',
 u'j_fajr': u'5:15',
 u'j_isha': u'10:15',
 u'jumuah_1': u'1:45',
 u'jumuah_2': u'2:45',
 u'midnight': u'12:37',
 u'month_date': u'12:37',
 u'sunrise': u'6:20',
 u'tahajjud': u'1:57'}
```

Comment: Thank you! Learned much from this.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome, if you inspect an element, then right-click on it and choose "Copy > Copy XPath" it should generate the xpath you need. [See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbSM7.png)

I'm not sure where you got that id value from, unless it changes periodically. Currently the value for that div's id is `slideshow-305-575473207d5b6`.

EDIT: Okay, yes it looks like this div's id is randomly generated (refresh the page a few times...should be different every time). So it'd be no use using this as your starting point. May as well go straight to the `td` elements, since they have their own id.